# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead, how to solve the one with dataset

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Folsom_irradiance.csv', encoding='gbk')
dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
dataPOV = dataset['ghi']
dataPOV = np.array(dataPOV).reshape(-1,1)
print("dataPOV:",dataPOV.shape)
N1=70000
N2 = N1+10000
dataAll = dataPOV[:N2,:]

global scaler
scaler = StandardScaler(copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True)
dataAll = scaler.fit_transform(dataAll)
```

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-1.21897049 -1.22302263 -1.21675063 ...  1.6377127   1.56019364
  1.84912833].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

got this error, how do i reshape the it ?, not sure what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: Is your data a single feature or single example? If so, just do what it tells you in the error.

Comment: its a single feature/column with many samples, but ive already reshaped it to (-1,1) and i still get the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a minimal reproducible example. This works

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((100000, 2)), columns=['ghi', 'jkl'])
dataPOV = dataset['ghi']
dataPOV = np.array(dataPOV).reshape(-1,1)
N1=70000
N2 = N1+10000
dataAll = dataPOV[:N2,:]
scaler = StandardScaler(copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True)
dataAll = scaler.fit_transform(dataAll)
```

Comment: i still get the same error, not sure why either

Comment: @CuBozo you tried this exact code and it still gave you an error? If so, you'll need to make or docker or binder or give really precise versions.  With the above code, I don't have any errors in a variety of environments.